# Erro no MuiThemeProvider

Tags: react, material-design

Boa noite, estou enfrentando um problema em um projeto react. Ao executar o mesmo, recebo o seguinte erro: "Failed prop type: The prop 'theme' is marked as required in `MuiThemeProvider`, but its value is `undefined`." Esse erro é por causa do MuiThemeProvider que tive que colocar pra aplicar o drawer no meu projeto. Pesquisei em vários fóruns e o que consegui ver é que esse é um erro relacionado a versão do material-ui, porém não consegui resolver mesmo assim.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import '../assets/scss/main.scss';
import img from '../assets/images/react.png';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  inputProps: {
    step: 300,
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
    border: '5px solid black',
    width: '100%',
  },
  paper1: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginTop: '13%',
  },
  img: {
    width: '45%',
  },
  appbar: {
    marginLeft: '-20.20%',
    marginTop: '-20%',
    width: '139.99%',
  },
});

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const state = {
    inputs: {},
  };

  const updateInputValue = (evt) => {
    state.inputs[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    console.log(state.inputs);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // console.log('handleSubmit', username, password);
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
      console.log({ displayErrors: true });
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return 0;
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appbar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
              <Drawer />
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
          <img src={img} alt="React" className={classes.img} /><br />
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <TextField id="email" type="email" label="Usuário" className={classes.user} value={state.inputs.username} onChange={evt => updateInputValue(evt)} /><br />
            <TextField id="password" type="password" label="Senha" className={classes.senha} value={state.inputs.password} onChange={evt => updateInputValue(evt)} />
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.paper1}>
              <Link to="/Orders">
                <Button type="submit" color="contrast">Login</Button>
              </Link>
            </AppBar>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

Esse é meu package.json: [image]

Answer (score 0):

O erro que você mencionou fala claramente qual o problema: você não está fornecendo a prop **theme**, que é requerida pelo componente `MuiThemeProvider`.

Só por curiosidade, você pode olhar no código fonte do componente `MuiThemeProvider` a [definição do prop type check aqui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3ba7b3ffdb2d5a819f6b0b0ce166f206d39a182b/src/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js#L114).

Me deparei com dois sites pro material-ui, e o correto para esse caso da pergunta é esse aqui: https://material-ui-next.com/api/mui-theme-provider/#muithemeprovider

Seguindo [esse exemplo aqui](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#muithemeprovider), você pode criar um theme usando `createMuiTheme()` do pacote `'material-ui/styles'`:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
const theme = createMuiTheme();

// ... dentro do seu componente
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* ... */}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
```